# Add .class file in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I know this is a noob question and maybe you can think that is a duplicate question, but none of the solutions it worked for me. Besides I have this problem since 2 days. The thing is, I am trying to add a .class file in java in Eclipse. This is the error:

[image]

This is the project structure

[image]

I added the file from a class folder and it didn't work.

[image]

I also tried to import the .class file in a zip. It didn't work also. The curious thing is that, when I autocomplete the text of the import, Eclipse recognizes it. The file should be added in *librerias.estructurasDeDatos.deDispersion* . I am using Eclipse 2018-12 (4.10.0). And also, I saw a lot of solutions using Maven, but I am not using it. Also, I would like to know, why in the Package Explorer view I can see .java files and not .class files, because my TablaHash.class it is added in the project. Any help would be good. I am sure it could be a silly solution, but I can't see what I am doing wrong.

[image]

**EDIT:** I have changed `lib` folder to this and it doesn`t work.

[image]

Comment: what is the content of `TablaHash.class`? java code or byte code? if first, file should be `TablaHash.java`; if second, file should be on the Java Build Path (and probably in a different folder, like `lib` or so - `Add Class Folder...` or `Add External Class Folder...` Button)

Comment: @user85421 it is byte code. And I have changed the name of the folder to `lib` and it does not work. In my question you can see java build path, the file it is add.

Comment: and your `class` folder needs a `librerias` folder, which needs a `estructurasDeDatos` and that a `deDispersion` which contain the `TablaHash.class` (it must reflect the package structure). Note that if that class file comes from another project, it may be easier to just add that project (`Projects` tab)

Comment: @user85421 If I understand you well, it doesn't work. I edited the question.

Comment: the folder added to the class path (e.g. `eda/lib`) must have he `librerias` folder - but the whole project is strange: a java file and an (external?) class file in the same package (`...deDispersion`)

Comment: @user85421 I am sorry but i don't understand you. The TablaHash.class file should be add in the package `librerias.estructurasDeDatos.deDispersion`, so other classes can import it from there. Should I changed the name of the folder `librerias`?

Comment: In the Java bytecode of the `.class` file the package name is encoded and the package cannot be changed by moving the file to another folder. The package given by the `.class` file and the folder must match and cannot be changed without recompiling it.

Comment: Java searches the class file using the package hierarchy, that means, assuming that `/eda/lib` is one folder in the classpath, java will search `TablaHash.class` in the directory `/eda/lib/librerias/estructurasDeDatos/deDispersion/` not in just `/eda/lib/` Please the sun/oracle documentation [How the Java Launcher Finds User Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/findingclasses.html#userclass)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's suppose I have a project `so.lib` where I have the Source for `TablaHash.java`:

```java
package librerias.estructurasDeDatos.deDispersion;

public class TablaHash {

    public String test() {
        return "OK, I'm here";
    }
}
```

in another project `so.test` I have a `Main` class that uses previous class:

```java
package so.test;

import librerias.estructurasDeDatos.deDispersion.TablaHash;


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var tabla = new TablaHash();
        System.out.println(tabla.test());
    }
}
```

---

### Option 1 - Use first project in second project

Add the first (library) project to the classpath of the Projects tab in the second porject settings.

Project structures and settings of `so.test`:

[image: Project Structure] [image: Project Settings]

---

### Option 2 - Copy class file

Copy the class file(s) **and** directories in a `lib` folder of second project. Add the `lib` folder to the classpath in the `Libraries` tab. (I used `lib`, but the folder can be any (valid) name)

Project structures and settings of `so.test`:

[image: Project Structure] [image: Project Settings]

Note: the folder structure/hierarchie inside `lib` is the same as from the project where the class file was located (same as the package hierarchie):

[image: Folder Structure]

Comment: Option 2 it worked! It seems that I have to add in the build path `lib` folder, only `lib` folder. And I was adding `lib/librerias/estructurasDeDatos/deDispersion`. But I would like to know why if I add only ´lib´ folder it works. Thank you so much for your help @user85421

Comment: since the first package name is `libraries`, java searches that folder in `lib`, then it searches the second package name inside that folder and so on... the folder structure must be the same as the package structure. better explained in the link I posted in last comment

Comment: you could also have `lib/datos/algoMas/NoSabes.class` for a class in package `datos.algoMas` (eventually used by `TablaHash`). Or any other packages at *same location* without having to add another entry to the classpath

Comment: BTW: if creating a JAR file, the folder structure must also match the package one, that is `librerias` should also be a top folder in the JAR